# phantomjs - Can't find variable: fetch

Tags: phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to generate pdf from html. The webpage is written in react and I guess it's too new version for phantomjs because I am getting error:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:150649
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fetch
```

How can I parse the page to old js? here is the code:

```
 var system = require('system');
 var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("http://127.0.0.1:3000/home",  function () {
window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('/opt/report.pdf');
            phantom.exit();
}, 100000);
});
```

Comment: you probably need a server-side fetch package installed like `node-fetch` https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: Tried, same error. Server is running on express, by the way.

Comment: you have to include the fetch package somewhere, not just install it, somewhere at the start of your app you have to include `global.fetch = require('node-fetch');`

Comment: Still the same error there. :(